# Drill down the haystack search results with facets but not changing the facet results

Tags: django, django-haystack, facet

I have search results showing with facet options for drilling down the data.  When a facet is selected it then changes the facet results.  So if I am originally showing "places (10)", "images (5)", "people (3)", and "All (18)" as faceting options and I click on images I would still like to see all the others too even though the search results changed.  Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: should probably consider changing the answer since it does seem to be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into problems with this too. The only answer we could find was to re-run the query each time without the drill-down to get the top-level facet results.

Comment: There is always a way, see: http://piran.com.au/2011/10/django-haystack-how-to-keep-the-original-facet-counts-when-drilling-down/

Comment: @Rich that link has rotted.

Answer (score 7):

I just did this and it's actually quite achievable without rerunning the original search query. you just need to use session to store the original facets.

Here's my actual working code:

```
from haystack.views import FacetedSearchView

class StickyFacetedSearchView (FacetedSearchView):

    def top_level_facets(self):
        """
        When selecting a facet to drill down the results, 
        we need to keep the top level facet counts
        """
        stored_query = self.request.session.get('query', None)

        if stored_query != self.query:
            self.request.session['query'] = self.query
            self.request.session['facet_counts'] = self.results.facet_counts()

        return self.request.session['facet_counts'] # Fail loudly

    def extra_context(self):
        """ add base_facets to extra_context"""
        extra = super(StickyFacetedSearchView, self).extra_context()
        extra['base_facets'] = self.top_level_facets()
        return extra
```

Stick the above view in an app called 'mysearch' or similar, then use mysearch.StickyFacetedSearchView in urls.py instead of FacetedSearchView.

To access them use base_facets in the template, rather than facets.

It works perfectly.

Comment: does this work even with you drill down a few levels with facets?

Comment: Nathan, yes base_facets is always the original facet counts of the base query.

Comment: Does this work if a user opens two tabs and does different searches in each?