# how to disable nesting (drill-down) in haystack faceting

Tags: django, count, django-haystack, faceted-search

I am using [`django-haystack`](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack) in one of my projects and am using the `faceting` feature to show facets for different fields. Currently the facets look something like this:

```
Places

    - New York (51)
    - Los Angeles (22)
    - Chicago (20)
    - Houston (38)
    - Philadelphia (15)

Price Range (in USD)

    - $2000 - $4000 (10)
    - $4000 - $6000 (15)
    - $6000 - $10000 (8)
    - $10000 - $15000 (4)
```

Currently what happens is if say i click on any of the link in the places (Ex. New York), The facet count for `Places` is updated. and it looks something like:

```
Places

    - New York (51)
    - Chicago (3)
    - Los Angeles (1)
    - Houston (0)
    - Philadelphia (0)
```

and then if I click on another place say Los Angeles the count changes to something like

```
Places

    - Los Angeles (22)
    - Philadelphia (3)
    - New York (1)
    - Chicago (0)
    - Houston (0)
```

What I am looking to do is not to drill down the selected facet but all the other facets. So if I click on a place, I would want the place facet to stay in the same order and show the original counts but other facets to show the nested result counts. So if I click on one of the places in the original facets mentioned above results look something like this. (Say I click on New York:)

```
Places #The Original Count and order is maintained here

    - New York (51)
    - Los Angeles (22)
    - Chicago (20)
    - Houston (38)
    - Philadelphia (15)

Price Range (in USD) # This facet has the updated result count

    - $2000 - $4000 (2)
    - $4000 - $6000 (5)
    - $6000 - $10000 (1)
    - $10000 - $15000 (0)
```

How can I achieve this ?

I also went through a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893732/drill-down-the-haystack-search-results-with-facets-but-not-changing-the-facet-re) here on stackflow, but I did not find any of the answers reliable.

@DanielRoseman's answer suggest to re-run an empty query each time a user makes a request through facets. I am not sure if making two queries for each request is a very good idea. Would that not slow down the whole process ?

@Rich's answer suggest to save the initial counts into sessions and pass it to the context with each request. This seems like a better solution but I have the same worries as @StephenPaulger as most of the time users using our product will have multiple browser tabs open and which will mess up the counts in other tabs.

Is there anything else that could be done to achieve this. How come such a vital functionality is not a part of the haystack project itself ?

Comment: I've run into the same problem, and ended up re-running the query. I don't think there's a standard way to solve this, I guess it'd be a good feature request for haystack's devs.

Comment: @FacundoOlano: I finally ended up writing my own Facet objects that keeps a track of the original counts and the new counts and passing them to the template instead of directly using haystack's `facet_counts()` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the solr backend you can get it to disregard part of a filter for a facet like so:

```
# facet by category but disregard any category filters on this query
squeryset = squeryset.facet('{!ex=category}category')
```

so for yours replace category with places I would imagine (and probably be places_exact)

Now I'm trying to work out how to do this with elasticsearch